# Modify dataframe in place using nan values from passed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So i have the following sample df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,1,2,3],'Origin':['int','int','pot','pot'],'Origin2':['pot','int','int','int']})

   Id Origin Origin2
0   1    int     pot
1   1    int     int
2   2    pot     int
3   3    pot     int
```

And i do the following replace command

```
df.loc[df['Id'].eq(1)].apply(lambda x : x.replace('int':np.nan))
```

How could i update the original df, with both new columns using indexes.
I tried `df.update` but after checking the documentation, i noticed it doesnt substitute 'non na' values by nan values?
For better understanding, the columns in the index [0,1] ('id'= 1). Substitute the string 'int' by np.nan

Wanted result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,1,2,3],'Origin':[np.nan,np.nan,'pot','pot'],'Origin2':['pot',np.nan,'int','int']})

   Id Origin Origin2
0   1    NaN     pot
1   1    NaN     NaN
2   2    pot     int
3   3    pot     int
```

Comment: can you please add the expected output ?

Comment: do you want to replace int by nan in the entire dataframe ?

Comment: `df[["Origin", "Origin2"]] = df[["Origin", "Origin2"]].replace('int', np.nan)` ?

Comment: @MichaelS. That doesnt work neither, it is index based if run that command it will replace entirely my column by a filtered version of it. I just want to replace those specific filter valued by  np.nan

Comment: @srinath Added as request, no i do not desire to substitute int by the entirety of my dataframe. As the given wanted result shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mixed boolean/label indexing:

```
m = df['Id'].eq(1)

df.loc[m, ['Origin', 'Origin2']] = df.loc[m, ['Origin', 'Origin2']].replace('int', np.nan)
```

Output:

```
   Id Origin Origin2
0   1    NaN     pot
1   1    NaN     NaN
2   2    pot     int
3   3    pot     int
```

Answer (score 4):

```
mask = df.Id.eq(1)
cols = ['Origin','Origin2']
df.loc[mask, cols] = df.replace('int', np.nan)
```

Output:

```
   Id Origin Origin2
0   1    NaN     pot
1   1    NaN     NaN
2   2    pot     int
3   3    pot     int
```

Comment: This is also a good one, although you do substitute, in the entire df after the equal sign. So i guessing is less efficient than mozway

Comment: ye, you could add `loc[mask, cols]` to the right side as well for better efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

This might be more ugly than you want but it's all I have:

```py
#  Recreate DF plus an extra column to check the code
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,1,2,3],'Origin':['int','int','pot','pot'],'Origin2':['pot','int','int','int'], 'Test':['pot','pot','int','int']})

# Relevant Code
index = [0,1]                         # Known index that you want to change 'int' to 'NaN'
columns = ["Origin", "Origin2"]       # Columns you want to change `int` to `NaN`
for column in columns:
    df[column][index] = df[column][index].replace('int', np.nan)
```

Output:

```
    Id  Origin  Origin2     Test
0   1   NaN     pot         pot
1   1   NaN     NaN         pot
2   2   pot     int         int
3   3   pot     int         int
```

Comment: All good, check @[BeRT2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73083535/modify-dataframe-in-place-using-nan-values-from-passed-dataframe/73084109#73084109)'s answer. He had it for the `eq(1)` part. I thought you just wanted access to all indexes, not to change it based on the index of a value in the `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

This is bit different from another answer because I'm not using `Id` column here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,1,2,3],'Origin':['int','int','pot','pot'],'Origin2':['pot','pot','int','int']})

    df['Origin'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x['Origin'] == 'int' else 'int', axis = 'columns')
df['Origin2'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x['Origin2'] == 'int' else 'int', axis = 'columns'

    Id Origin Origin2
0   1    NaN     pot
1   1    NaN     NaN
2   2    pot     int
3   3    pot     int
```

Comment: He wants it for all "Origin" columns

Comment: I wrote the answer based on your previous `Wanted result`. Mozway already answered your question.

Comment: I'm not OP. OP had a comment that seems to be deleted where he stated that he has multiple columns and wants only the `Origin` columns to be affected.